# CSS style not synchronizing with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I would prefer not to use jquery just for simplicity. I have three websites which one page cycles through. I want the webpages to be scaled each by a different scalar value. I tried applying a class to each page but with the switch statement it's supposed to zoom 2x on google 4x on yahoo and .5x on ebay. However, when I run the code it will go google at zoom 2x. Then it goes to yahoo at .5x then ebay at .5x zoom. I don't care about efficiency, it's only going to be three pages this scrolls through so it can be hardcoded. Thanks

```
<style>
#wrap { width: 1390px; height: 690px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#frame.first { width: 1390px; height: 690px; border: 0px solid black; }
#frame.first { zoom: 2; -moz-transform: scale(2); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
#frame.second { width: 1395px; height: 695px; border: 0px solid black; }
#frame.second { zoom: 4; -moz-transform: scale(1); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
#frame.third { width: 1395px; height: 695px; border: 0px solid black; }
#frame.third { zoom: .5; -moz-transform: scale(1); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frames = Array('http://www.google.com, 5,
                       'http://www.yahoo.com', 5,
                       'http://www.ebay.com', 5);

var i = 0, len = frames.length;
function ChangeSrc()
{
if (i >= len) { i = 0; }
switch(i)
{
case 0:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'first';
  document.getElementById('frame').className
  break;
case 1:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'second';
  document.getElementById('frame').className
  break;
case 2:
  document.getElementById('frame').className = 'third';
  document.getElementById('frame').className
  break;
}      
  document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
  setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}
window.onload = ChangeSrc;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <iframe src="" class="" id="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create thumbnails for external iframes? I doubt whether this is going to be possible at all because of the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what is causing your issue but you seem to be missing a closing quotation on Google:

```
var frames = Array('http://www.google.com, 5,
                   'http://www.yahoo.com', 5,
                   'http://www.ebay.com', 5);
```

should be:

```
var frames = Array('http://www.google.com', 5,
                   'http://www.yahoo.com', 5,
                   'http://www.ebay.com', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable should NOT be named frames. You are messing up window.frames when you name the var frames. Name it to something else.

Using a for loop is wrong thing to use here since it will not give you any time for the pages to load. You probably want to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to call each iteration.

Comment: Can you show me how to use setTimeout to call each iteration? Thanks